# Ruby/Compass Sass syntax error

Tags: ruby, compass-sass

First time user of Compass here, having an issue getting my sass compiler to work. I followed a tutorial online and I'm getting this error:

**Error**

```
syntaxError on line ["24"] of C: C:/Users/Casey/Sites/devdesktop/bootstrap-subtheme/themes/less_subtheme/config.rb:1: 
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
..."/themes/less_subtheme" css_dir = "css" sass_dir = "assets/s...
```

**config.rb file**

```
ruby http_path = "/themes/less_subtheme" css_dir = "css" sass_dir = "assets/sass" images_dir = "assets/images" javascripts_dir = "js" fonts_dir = "bootstrap/fonts/bootstrap" generated_images_dir = "img" http_images_path = http_path + "/" + generated_images_dir http_generated_images_path = http_images_path output_style = (environment == :production) ? :compressed : :expanded
```

I've rewritten the code I copied to make sure no *funny* quotes or blank spaces were copied over and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because all of your code is on one line and there is "ruby" appearing at the beginning. Try this

```
http_path = "/themes/less_subtheme"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "assets/sass"
images_dir = "assets/images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
fonts_dir = "bootstrap/fonts/bootstrap"
generated_images_dir = "img"
http_images_path = http_path + "/" + generated_images_dir
http_generated_images_path = http_images_path
output_style = (environment == :production) ? :compressed : :expanded
```